# "spawn_entity.py" executable not found

Tags: ros2, gazebo-ros, robot-description, spawn, launch

i have created a workspace in ros2 humble in Ubuntu 22.04 and i am trying to spawn the robot in gazebo empty world using the following command:

> ros2 run gazebo_ros launch spawn_entity.py -topic robot_description -entity bot_name

but i am getting the following error:

No executable found

i tried sourcing my workspace using source install/setup.bash but it didn't work

Comment: @ssarkar - you should probably post that as an answer

Answer (score 0):

`spawn_entity` is a node, and not a launch file. If you remove the launch word from your command, it should be working fine.

So, the command should look like the following:

```sh
ros2 run gazebo_ros spawn_entity.py -topic robot_description -entity bot_name
```